# CSS Bootstrap - How to make image rows same sizes while maintaing fluidity?

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

I have one row of 5 images and two rows of 4 images as shown below:

[image]

The problem is when I use col-md in layouting, the pictures in the first row becomes smaller compared to the last two rows since that's how bootstrap was made. How do I make the images same sizes and still maintain responsiveness?

Here is my current code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1nTQDh-F35LayxXtm6WMZK6U6eYmwdrzj" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1YNxNg4k2RdZ1zmm-VjiljEU6JpKc1s5q" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1RnX-U-YyU5kP2xbe7zWE9oJcU78PgMCW" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1GMKk5IW_iI55gqE6ye0Ul4nmssrIfX19" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=144ezEQEDozijf8Vk3dB8QYgoqtCfEWuG" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1F0XPaqsKV3G6JzI4SNaH5tlPSJXxkPXr" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1MNQ7qgEjAxxKuif5pJqiB2b8zRirTs3H" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1IN6UTqnfhX3vI1_AAIKafDEW7i_66EWg" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1x91NNnHlE0PpZoAWh0ueMIkkgC-dSUMn" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=106oTjYXJQBg-cPTL_FXW-HQwDk21gzkd" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1FuqE9s-_nXO3Jw-RCJKnzPlBOujV_m5_" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1mLywhfH8KMlEViBTQ-GjJrjC3dqWxvDc" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WO8eYFq8QlTfIxmfuWqFZNR8heDJE93I" class="img-fluid"">
    </div>
</div>
```

For the col-half offset:

```
.col-half-offset{
    margin-left:4.166666667%
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4? Do you expect the images to be the same width eventhough you have 5 in one, and 4 in the others? I'm not understanding the desired result.

Comment: Yes, same width even with 4. Either the size of four cards will become the size for the 5 cards or vice versa. The goal is to make it all the same sizes.